# btc transaction stuck from last 3 days on blockchain

Tags: blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions

I've sent a transaction on bittrex wallet, but accidentally included too little fee. What can I do to cancel the transaction or speed up the transaction's confirmation?

transaction id:

https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/007f4527695f69eac30d6431f50a7b3b5befc92b99c7d8a217e0ebc37c999961/

https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/9e6973cf77e7148e81c0edfca0b25a6463c80d2248c31f9b43ee0027f52d1092/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you put a very small fee for the transaction. As the mempool is pretty cluttered your transaction may take quite some time to pass through. Did you send your BTC from a platform?

Check the mempool here:
https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#all

Comment: Send it from coinome to bittrex. Can you tell approx how long it will take for confirmation.